# In the Model derivative API, if a translation fails, will cloud credits be consumed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using the Model derivative API to convert ifc to svf. Will cloud credits be consumed if the conversion fails?

Answer (score 1):

When translation fails cloud credits will not be consumed.